# DateTime formats C#

Tags: c#

I have a string which needs to be converted and validated to a DateTime. The string is in the following format 'dd.mm.yy'
I am trying to convert it to DateTime using the following

```
string format = "dd.mm.yy";
date = DateTime.ParseExact(current.Substring(aiRule.AiLength), format, 
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but unfortunately this fails. 
The question is how to convert a string in the format 'dd.mm.yy' to a DateTime ?
Thank you

Comment: can you show your input string and the result of: current.Substring(aiRule.AiLength) ?

Comment: As a general rule, saying "X fails" doesn't help the people helping you. Try to be specific - give examples of inputs, expected outputs, actual outputs, or error messages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`mm` means "minutes". I suspect you want `"dd.MM.yy"`. See MSDN for more information about [custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

(In particular, read the part about the ["yy" specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#yySpecifier) and how it chooses which century to use. If you can possibly change the input to use a four digit year, that could save you some problems...)

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell something "heretical". If `dd.MM.yy` (with 2 or 4 `yy`) is the format of your local culture, then you could let the `DateTime.Parse` (not `ParseExact`!) do its work without setting it to `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, or perhaps setting it to your local culture like `new CultureInfo("it-IT")`.

Answer (score 0):

the string format should be like this....

```
string Format =  "dd.MM.yy"


 mm is for showing minutes 

 MM is for showing months..
```

I hope it will helps you...

Answer (score 0):

As earlier posts has already pointed out, mm means minutes and MM means months. I ran this test snippet and it works as expected:

```
string format = "dd.MM.yy";
string date = "27.10.11";
DateTime result;
result = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```